# Not able to integrate bootstrap5.3.3 in rails 5

Tags: bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-2.4

I have downloaded bootstrap 5.3.3 (scss files) and keep them in `app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_files/` directory

Below is my `application.scss` file

```
@import 'bootstrap/functions';
//@import 'bootstrap/variables';
```

On start of rails server, @import 'bootstrap/functions' works but on uncommenting `//@import 'bootstrap/variables';` I got `$color: "var(--bs-emphasis-color-rgb)" is not a color for` rgba' error.

I tried to downgrade bootstrap to 5.2, 5.1, 5.0 but none works

**JS** files are present in `app/javascript/bootstrap_files/` directory.

I tried to use `bootstrap` gem but that have some other libraries dependencies , so I cant use that.

I have gem **sass-rails** & other `scss` files are already working.

I am using RAILS 5.1.7, RUBY 2.4